# I have a problem with GPU support in Tensorflow v2.15.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, gpu

I have a problem with tensorflow and its GPU support. I got two setups running. One is working, the other one is not:

1. Setup (working):

- Tensorflow v2.5.0
- cuda v.2.12
- python 3.9.13

2. Setup (not working):

- Tensorflow v2.15.0
- cuda v2.12
- python 3.9.13

When i try to find the recognized devices by tensorflow within the 2. setup,

```
(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

It wont find my (only) GPU.
The 1. and the 2. setup both run on the same PC. The second setup is just a virtual python environment with another tensorflow version.
The versions in setup 2 should be compatible with eachother. Regardless, its not working.
I allready tried:

- Using diffrent versions of cuda
- changing the system environment variables

What can i do, to get the 2. Setup running with my GPU?

Comment: is this on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow 2.15.0 is not compatible with CUDA 2.12. According to the TensorFlow website, TensorFlow 2.15.0 requires CUDA 10.0 and cuDNN 7.4.

You have to download and install [CUDA 10.0 from the NVIDIA website](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.0-download-archive).

Comment: This is wrong, see [here for a list of compatible versions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu). TF 2.15 is listed with CUDA 2.12 and CuDNN 8.9. Maybe you mixed it up with TF 1.15, which needs CUDA 10.0.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, anything above TF2.10 won't work on Windows anymore (for detecting GPU).  I'm trying to do the wsl method to get TF2.15 working in Visual Studio Code notebooks but I can't get it to work, but an environment with TF2.10 still works.